# Facebook graph api - duplicate posts returned when using page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the graph explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with any access token (no permissions, some permissions, etc), on this simple endpoint to get the posts of a page: `{page-id}/posts`

Then I get the posts back. Great!

However, when I get the page access token for this page and use that on the SAME endpoint then I get duplicated information for every post. Literally twice the information, same ids, no differences at all.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and if there is any way to stop it? (Preferably without having to de-dupe the data after I've fetched it?)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. It's not just you :) I'm using a long lived page access token

Comment: There's a bug report in Facebook's platform bug tracker about this at the moment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/706819176094748